# Opening links but not iFrames in webview

Tags: cocoa, iframe, webview

I have an webView in a Cocoa application which I edit the contents programatically. What I wanted to do was make clicked links open in the users default browser, so I added the code at the bottom of this question. It works perfectly but if there is an iFrame on the page that loads it will open the iFrame contents in the default browser and not display the frame correctly in my app. Is there a way to tell the webview to open the links but do nothing to iFrames?

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request
          frame:(WebFrame *)frame
decisionListener:(id)listener 
{

    // Open it in the default browser
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if (url)
    {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
        [listener ignore];
    }
    else
    {
        [listener use];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine [the navigation-action dictionary](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Action_Dictionary_Keys).

Comment: link is no more available. i need to log java script and webview log and write it in file. any possible way to implement for mac osx application?